# The DbContext of type cannot be pooled because it does not have a single public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-2.0

I am trying to upgrade our current .Net Core application from 1.1 to 2.0 and am getting this runtime error: "The DbContext of type 'CoreContext' cannot be pooled because it does not have a single public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions".

It is caused by using the new IServiceCollection.AddDbContextPool<> function. When I use IServiceCollection.AddDbContext<> it still works.

This application is DB-First, so I generate all our contexts using 'Scaffold-DbContext'. Due to that, and the need to inject other services I have an extension on every context like this:

```
public partial class CoreContext
{
    public CoreContext(
        DbContextOptions<CoreContext> options,
        IUserService userService,
        IAuditRepository auditRepository
        ) : base(options) {...}
}
```

Whenever I run the Scaffold-DbContext I just remove the autogenerated Constructor from CoreContext, but even if I put it in there I still get this error.

```
public partial class CoreContext : DbContext
{
    public CoreContext(DbContextOptions<CoreContext> options) : base(options) {}
}
```

I've already updated Program.cs to the new style:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
}
```

And the Startup.cs is pretty straightforward:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddDbContextPool<CoreContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(absConnectionString));
    ...
}
```

I am using Autofac for DI if that helps. For now I'll default back to the non-Pooling alternative, but it would be nice to take advantage of this feature.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you discover how to get around it, or are you back to non-pooling? Would be great to be able to use this new feature.

Comment: I reverted to the non-pooling option. Haven't really had time to lament it yet, need to keep moving.

Comment: @JeffKeslinke Did you fix this issue?

Comment: The exception message is crystal clear: the context requires "a single public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions".

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When using `DbContext Pooling`, your own state (e.g. private fields) in your derived DbContext class will be preserved. Which means the lifetime of your services is now `singleton`. That's why you shouldn't have other injected services here. 
But it's possible to query the required services this way:
First we should use the `UseInternalServiceProvider` method on `DbContextOptionsBuilder` to tell EF which service provider to use for its services. This service provider must have all the services configured for EF and any providers. So we should register EF Services manually:

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
```

And then introduce the application's services provider which now includes the EF Services too:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>((serviceProvider, optionsBuilder) =>
{
   optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("...");
   optionsBuilder.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
});
```

After that define these namespaces:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

And now you can access the registered services in the application within the 
ApplicationDbContext class using the following methods

```
var siteSettings = this.GetService<IOptionsSnapshot<SiteSettings>>();
```

Or

```
var siteSettings = this.GetInfrastructure().GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<SiteSettings>>();
```

`this` is the current instance of the DbContext.

Comment: Nice answer +1, but a note should be added that `optionsBuilder.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider)` is not essential and calling `GetService<T>` will resolve from the default provider.

Comment: Related to the above comment https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/pull/8622

Comment: how to get a service that has parameter. i.e what if SiteSettings has other dependencies, in my case it throws compiler error

Answer (score 25):

Remove the default constructor in the DbContext class, this worked for me

Comment: This says exactly the same thing as a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57480863/861716) ("remove your empty constructor"), so I can only conclude that this is meant to confirm that answer. Please don't repeat answers to confirm them, it only adds noise. Vote for them instead.

Answer (score 11):

> "because it does not have a single public constructor accepting a
> single parameter of type DbContextOptions"

If you have any public constructors apart from one that accepts DbContextOptions, you need to remove them or make them non-public in order to use context pooling.

Also, there are restrictions on what can be done by overriding the OnConfiguring method.  This is referenced in the documentation here but it isn't explicit about what those restrictions are:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/index#dbcontext-pooling

Comment: The problem is that it's Scaffold-DbContext that puts the extra constructor in

Comment: (at least it does now - didn't back in August)

Comment: Still adds it. I don't see why the most advanced features always have to cause the most pain. It makes you think you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Perfect answer. This error should read "because it has more than one public..." not the way it reads. In our culture "because you don't have a single X" reads like "X or more is fine but you have zero" eg: "because you don't have a single dollar you are broke" ... While the current phrase is accurate it is also inherently ambiguous in our culture.

Answer (score 4):

This issue is mostly encountered when you "Scaffold-Dbcontext" and two constructors are generated.

Simple Solutions:

1. **AddDbContextPool**:
   If you want to use AddDbContextPool, remove your empty constructor and maintain the one with the DbContextOptionsBuilder. Note that in this case you might have to provide the options, as suggested in the previous posts.
2. **AddDbContext**:
   With AddDbContext, you can have both constructors/Overloads

Note: **AddDbContextPool** is preferred for **performance** reasons!

Answer (score 3):

in some case need to
remove the constractor with zero parameter

> ```
> //public MyContext()
> //{
> //}
> ```

or use

"AddDbContext"

instead of

"AddDbContextPool"

in startup.cs => ConfigureServices()

> services.AddDbContext(options =>
> options.UseSqlServer(absConnectionString));