# Using Entity Framework Core DbContext Pooling with Simple Injector

Tags: entity-framework-core, dbcontext, simple-injector, ef-core-2.1

Looking at the examples of how to use db context pool I see it was designed to be used with `ServiceCollection`:

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddDbContextPool<AdventureWorksContext>(options => { //options })
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

But what about Simple Injector? is it possible to register DB pooling in the Simple Injector container?

p.s. My app is not ASP.NET MVC, it's just a kinda DAL

Comment: Are you following [Simple Injector's integration guide](https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore)? If you cross-wire your `DbContext` (either by calling `CrossWire<EfQueries>()` or by using `AutoCrossWireAspNetComponents`, you'll that that pooling behavior for free.

Comment: Steven, thank you for your reply, but I'm afraid that can't be done as it's not mvc application. It's just a class library, that may be called from a console application. Are there any other workarounds?

Comment: Your class library should not use a DI Container, so that would solve your problem elegantly. Only startup projects, like the console application, should make registrations and resolve them.

Comment: @Steven how would you achieve this in a .net core console app?

Answer (score 15):

## EF Core DbContext pooling in ASP.NET Core

When integrating Simple Injector in ASP.NET Core, you keep framework and third-party components inside the .NET Core configuration system. This means that enabling Entity Framework Core context pooling is done exactly as Microsoft documents it:

```cs
services.AddDbContextPool<BloggingContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

As Simple Injector [does not replace the built-in configuration system](https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore), you will have to [instruct](https://simpleinjector.org/servicecollection#cross-wiring-third-party-services) Simple Injector to automatically load missing registrations (such as your `DbContext`) from the .NET Core configuration system. This can be done by using the `AddSimpleInjector` and `UseSimpleInjector` extension methods, as shown here.

```cs
private SimpleInjector.Container container;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
        
    services.AddDbContextPool<BloggingContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));        

    services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options =>
    {
        options.AddAspNetCore();
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSimpleInjector(container);

    container.Verify();

    ...
}
```

Using this setup, the `BloggingContext` can be injected into any component that is resolved from Simple Injector, while the `BloggingContext` is pooled by Entity Framework. For intance:

```cs
// Application compoment registered in and resolved from Simple Injector
public class CommentIsNoSpamValidator : IValidator<PostComment>
{
    private readonly BloggingContext context;

    // Is injected with BloggingContext from IServiceCollection
    public CommentIsNoSpamValidator(BloggingContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(PostComment command)
    {
        // Complex business logic here.
    }
}
```

## EF Core DbContext pooling in a .NET (Core) Console application

When it comes to using Entity Framework Core context pooling in a .NET Core console application, the solution will be very similar, although you will have to set up a little bit more:

```cs
public void Main()
{
    var container = new Container();

    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    
    services.AddDbContextPool<BloggingContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
            
    services.AddSimpleInjector(container);

    services
        .BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true)
        .UseSimpleInjector(container);

    container.Verify();

    // Run application code
    using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container))
    {
        var service = container.GetInstance<MainService>();
        service.DoAwesomeStuff();
    }
}
```

So in the end, the DbContext's lifetime is managed by the MS.DI scope, but that scope is managed by Simple Injector's scope.

## EF Core DbContext pooling in a library

In case you are building a library, i.e. a non-startup project, please stop what you're doing. Only the application's startup assembly should have a [Composition Root](https://mng.bz/K1qZ), and only the Composition Root should use a DI Container (such as Simple Injector or MS.DI's `ServiceCollection`). All other libraries in your application should stay oblivious of the (possible) existence of a Container.

Comment: Thanks @Steven, this is very helpful!  So if I'm understanding this correctly, everywhere you want to use an injected DbContext, you need to wrap it in: `using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container)) { }` if it will be called by the console app?  That's not needed in ASP.NET Core given that each request is scoped already, but if you had shared code and wrapped it in the SI scope, will that have any effect if called in as ASP.NET Core request?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but in general, you should resolve stuff within an active scope. That's what happens in ASP.NET Core when you configured `UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping`. Starting a scope is something you should only do inside your Composition Root; nowhere else. Never inside a library.

Comment: Right, that makes perfect sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

`container.Register(() => 
     serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AdventureWorksContext>());`

to have the ServiceProvider resolve the dependency as it's requested.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Steven's excellent answer, here's his console application answer, but with the context (implicitly) using `UseInternalServiceProvider`.

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
services.AddSingleton<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory>(new Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory());
services.AddSingleton<IInterface>(new MyImplemenation());

services.AddDbContextPool<EFViewAndManyToManyDb>(optionsBuilder => {
  optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("");
});

services.AddSimpleInjector(container);

services
  .BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true)
  .UseSimpleInjector(container);
```

[Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46048500) you'd want to use `UseInternalServiceProvider`. TLDR: if your `DbContext` has a dependencies, e.g. `IInterface`. You'll also need to add the `SimpleInjector.Integration.ServiceCollection` Nuget package.