# Create EF Core Context once per request in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

After reading a lot on the subject it looks like a good approach is to create a context once per request.

To achive this, in in Startup.cs I have declared two statics objects

```
public class Startup
{
    public static DbContextOptionsBuilder<MCContext> optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MCContext>();
    public static MCContext db = null;
```

then init optionsBuilder when the app starts (so only once):

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);
}
```

while db at each request:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    db = db ?? new MCContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    await next.Invoke(); 
});
```

Then when I need the context in a controller or in a razor page cs I can get it using Startup.db:

```
User cur = await Startup.db.User.Where(x => x.Id == uid).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I do not Dispose the Context as per [here](https://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext/)

As I'm not familiar with DI I wonder if this approach is correct or if I am missing anything.

Comment: If you use DI properly then almost all of this code goes away. You should really learn how to use it.

Comment: This is more or less the standard way to approach it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2 If it's still causing bother I'll do an extended example

Answer (score 15, accepted):

base on [What is new in EF Core 2.0 - EF Core | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#dbcontext-pooling)

### If you want a new context once per request : AddDbContext

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddDbContext<MCContext >(
     options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
 }
```

then you can

```
public class TiketsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MCContext _context;

    public TiketsController (MCContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
 }
```

> The basic pattern for using EF Core in an ASP.NET Core application
>   usually involves registering a custom DbContext type into the
>   dependency injection system and later obtaining instances of that type
>   through constructor parameters in controllers. This means a new
>   instance of the DbContext is created for each requests.

### but if you need High Performance/Safe reuse : AddDbContextPool

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddDbContextPool<MCContext >(
     options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
 }
```

then you can

```
public class TiketsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MCContext _context;

    public TiketsController (MCContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
 }
```

> If this method is used, at the time a DbContext instance is requested
>   by a controller we will first check if there is an instance available
>   in the pool. Once the request processing finalizes, any state on the
>   instance is reset and the instance is itself returned to the pool.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed! I'm getting "cannot be pooled because it does not have a single public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions." but I'm now looking into this

Comment: @Pietro " [you have any public constructors apart from one that accepts DbContextOptions, you need to remove them or make them non-public in order to use context pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45904622/4879683)"

Answer (score 0):

If you are not creating object, then don't dispose it. Let IOC container handle it.

btw, I don't think this block of code is required. MCContext is a dependency, so its instance creation and injection gets done by IOC container.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    db = db ?? new MCContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    await next.Invoke(); 
});
```