# Is there a reason why I can't have a default constructor when using AddDbContextPool? I want to unit test my dbcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

When every I have a default constructor like

```
public MyDbContext()
{
}
```

I get this error [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45804470/the-dbcontext-of-type-cannot-be-pooled-because-it-does-not-have-a-single-public)

But I want to have the default constuctor there so I can unit test my database and check if I am getting the right result. I am using MySQL as a DB by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to be aware, that your DbContext represents the tables in your database and the relations between those tables. Every `DbSet<...>` in your `DbContext` represents one specific table. The rows in the table are represented by the class in the `<...>`.

These classes should be simple POCOs: the columns of your table are represented by the non-virtual properties, the virtual properties represent the relations between the tables.

Therefore, your class should not have any fields, nor procedures: a row of you table does not know how to `PerformFunction(...)`, does it?

If you want to add functionality to a row of your table, you should define an extension function of your class.

**But how am I suppose to test my database?**

I think, if you use a good database management system, you don't have to test it. IMHO the databases of MicroSoft and MySql are better tested than you can ever test.

However, you should test how you use your database! Do you store the items that you want to store, and do you retrieve the items that you want to retrieve? You should not worry about whether entity framework translates your queries correctly into SQL. That has been tested over and over again.

There are several common methods to test whether you use the database in a correct way.

**Use an In-Memory database that is controlled by entity framework**

This is the easiest one. Use for instance [nuget package effort](https://entityframework-effort.net/)

One of the constructors of a DbContext is the one with a parameter DbConnection. You use this constructor to connect to the in-memory database:

```
   class SchoolDbContext : DbContext
{
     public SchoolDbContext() : DbContext
     {
         // default constructor
     }

     public SchoolDbContext(DbConnection connection) : DbContext(dbConnection, false)
     {
         // constructor that uses the in-memory database
     }

     public DbSet<School> Schools {get; set;}
     public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
     ...
}
```

Usage in a test:

```
DbConnection inMemoryDbConnection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePersistent(testDbName);
using(var schoolDbContext = new SchoolDbContext(inMemoryConnection);
{
    // TODO: fill the database with test values
    ...
    IEqualityComparer<Student> studentComparer = ...
    var expectedObsoleteStudents = schoolDbContext.Students
        .Where(student => student.Obsolete)
        .ToHashSet(studentComparer);

    // Perform the Test:
    var testObject = new MyClassThatUsesADataBase()
    {
         SchoolDbContext = schoolDbContext();
    }

    // Test function: FetchObsoleteStudents, and check that the expected students are fetched
    var obsoleteStudents = testObject.FetchObsoleteStudents();
    Assert.IsTrue(expectedObsoleteStudents.EqualSet(obsoleteStudents);
}
```