# The DbContext of type cannot be pooled Error ...Can't Access Domain Classes with Context Classes's Object while using asp.net Core identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Asp.net Core identity along with My Domain Classes, I want to use DBContext object to Access Domain Classes For database operations.(Using EF Core Code first Approach).

For Ex. 1.1

```
var context = new AssignmentContext();
```

It Shows Error Because My Context class has no parameterless constructor, so I Create it Here is My DBContext Class

```
 public class AssignmentContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public AssignmentContext()
        {
        }

        public AssignmentContext(DbContextOptions<AssignmentContext> opt)
            : base(opt)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserTask> UserTasks { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<UserTask>().HasKey(ut => ut.AssignId);
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

Now when I am Creating a an object Like Example 1.1 in Action Method it throws error Mentioned in question.

Here is the startup File.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
            services.AddDbContextPool<AssignmentContext>(opt =>
                opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AssignMentDb")));


            services.AddSession();
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AssignmentContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
```

Gives Following Error

```
The DbContext of type  cannot be pooled because it does not have a single public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The DbContext of type cannot be pooled because it does not have a single public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45804470/the-dbcontext-of-type-cannot-be-pooled-because-it-does-not-have-a-single-public)

Comment: Try removing the parameterless constructor. The error message says you can only have a single public constructor, yet you have two

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 i Tried to remove parameterless Constructor it Gives me this error : There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'opt' of 'AssignmentContext.AssignmentContext(DbContextOptions<AssignmentContext>)'

Comment: @viveknuna I Referred that Question But that Doesn't answer My Question