# it does not have a public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions or has more than one constructor

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

when I try to call to Web Api from my .net core MVC project I received this error, Please help me to resolve this issue :

> The DbContext of type 'ApplicationDbContext' cannot be pooled because it does not have a public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions or has more than one constructor.

Comment: here's a high voted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45804470/the-dbcontext-of-type-cannot-be-pooled-because-it-does-not-have-a-single-public) which reported the same error message. pls take a look at them. If the solutions in this question didn't help you, pls provide more details to help us reproduce the issue at least.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I had two constructors in my DbContext class like below.

```
 public ApplicationDbContext()
        {

        }
 public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            // ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            // Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }
```

when I remove the parameterless constructor, the issue was fixed.